# Tablesorter addParser for date like "aa, dd.mm.yyyy"

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I try to sort dates like `"Di, 29.03.2016"` but this doesnt work because the Sorter doesnt have a AddParser for this format.

I know that the numbers should replace like `dd/mm/yyyy`,
but how should i replace `"Di, "`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I can't tell what language you're targeting ("Di" is the abbreviation for December in several languages), I think it might be easiest to use a date library like [sugar](http://sugarjs.com/dates#comparing_dates) or [datejs](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs) to parse those dates for you.

Make sure to set the locale *before* the following code.

### Sugar ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/4163/)):

```
Date.setLocale('es'); // Spanish
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'sugar',
    is: function() {
        return false;
    },
    format: function(s) {
        var date = Date.create ? Date.create(s) : s ? new Date(s) : s;
        return date instanceof Date && isFinite(date) ? date.getTime() : s;
    },
    type: 'numeric'
});
```

### DateJS ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/4164/)):

```
// make sure to load the desired locale file
// full list: https://github.com/datejs/Datejs/tree/master/build
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'datejs',
    is: function() {
        return false;
    },
    format: function(s) {
        var date = Date.parse ? Date.parse(s) : s ? new Date(s) : s;
        return date instanceof Date && isFinite(date) ? date.getTime() : s;
    },
    type: 'numeric'
});
```

Note: The above two demos are using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) & copied from [this file](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/parsers/parser-date.js), but these parsers will work in the original tablesorter (v2.0.5).

Note 2: There is also a [parser](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/parsers/parser-globalize.js) for [jQuery Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) ([demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-globalize.html)), but it is a bit more complicated to set up and use, so I didn't include it here; and the globalize parser may not work properly with the original version of tablesorter.